# Where can I find the official rules for Amateur Radio usage in Sweden

Tags: legal

A number of years ago I was very much into Ham Radio in Canada.

I have now moved to Sweden and am thinking about getting back into it again.

I can not find any clear set of rules as to how Sweden handles Ham Radio. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have been told anything from there are no rules this I do not believe to No you can not do that here.

One guy told me oh just walk into the store and buy what you want.

BTW I am as the bird flies about 10 km from the local airport

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 5):

The authoritative source for Swedish ham radio regulations is the Post and Telecom Authority (PTS): https://hamradio.pts.se/

There's useful information on the website of the Swedish amateur radio society, Föreningen Svenska Sändaramatörer (SSA, https://www.ssa.se/), as well.

Unfortunately, most of the resources are in Swedish.

In Sweden, as in most other countries, the amateur radio service is regulated. In order to transmit, you need an amateur radio certificate and you have to adhere to the band plans, power limits, etc.  In my experience, PTS is a bit more hands off than the regulators in some other countries, but there are clearly defined rules and you can't just do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

The following link at the national ham radio association (SSA) should be of interest:

https://www.ssa.se/international/amateur-radio-visitors-to-sweden/

It reads:
"Foreign radio amateurs with a CEPT HAREC (acc. T/R 61-01) license  staying for a longer time [than three months] and having an address in Sweden can apply for a permanent Swedish call sign. Apply to SSA, e-mail address signal@ssa.se."

The link also contains further links to Swedish bandplans for HF and VHF. They are written in Swedish, but should be decipherable with a dictionary if you don't read the language.

There's only one license level in Sweden, and it doesn't require cw.

Comment: I have been living here for over 10 years so got that covered thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will be useful to you.
https://www.ssa.se/international/amateur-radio-visitors-to-sweden/

Comment: Merhaba ve ham.stackexchange.com'a hoş geldiniz! Bu web sitesindeki yazılar [İngilizce](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) olmalıdır. Burada olmana sevindim! Lütfen tartışmalarımıza katılmak için bir çeviri web sitesi kullanmayı düşünün.  Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Posts on this website [should be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange).  I am glad that you are here!  Please consider using a translation website to participate in our discussions.